# What is the role of lock files in a system?

Tags: lock

I can see there are many `lock` file here and there in my system. What is the exact role and purpose of those `lock` files?

In my system I got this list,

```
/run/lock/whoopsie/lock
/proc/sys/dev/cdrom/lock
/var/lib/dpkg/lock
/var/lib/apt/lists/lock
/var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all lock files. [Link for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#Lock_files).

Different applications and daemons create their lock files, if they need to protect themselves from crashing or from corrupting information.

For example:

```
/run/lock/whoopsie/lock
```

lock for `whoopsie`, it is Ubuntu Error Reporting daemon. It collects information about crashes, so it need to protect some information from changes until it collects everything.

```
/proc/sys/dev/cdrom/lock
```

Lock file for you cdrom device. Only one application at a time can control `cdrom` device, that's why it is there. The same thing for every devices.

```
/var/lib/dpkg/lock
/var/lib/apt/lists/lock
/var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Lock file for package managers. They usually blocking their sources database

Also a little quote from `wikipedia`:

*The following example illustrates the interceding update problem:*

> 1. Process A reads a customer record from a file containing account information, including the customer's account balance and phone
>      number.
> 2. Process B now reads the same record from the same file so it has its own copy.
> 3. Process A changes the account balance in its copy of the customer record and writes the record back to the file.
> 4. Process B, which still has the original stale value for the account balance in its copy of the customer record, updates the account
>      balance and writes the customer record back to the file.
> 5. Process B has now written its stale account-balance value to the file, causing the changes made by process A to be lost.

This is one of examples. There many other situations that can lead to a problem. That's why OS need lock files

Answer (score 1):

They're generally used to ensure only one instance of an application is running at once.

This is particularly important in programs like `apt-get` which may break if more than one instance runs at once.